# How many different ways are there for a person to take the trip in one full week if the person wants to bike at least once?

Tags: combinatorics

From Monday to Friday, there are three ways to take a trip: driving, biking, or taking the bus. How many different ways are there for a person to take the trip in one full week if the person wants to bike at least once?

It seems that there are $3^5$ ways for the whole week and if there is no bike appears in a whole week, there are $2^5$ options. So the result seems $3^5-2^5$, right?

Comment: I think this is right. If you really want to check your answer, there's a tedious inclusion-exclusion argument you can use (although 5 days is too complicated -- maybe try with fewer)

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are $S:=\{1,2,3\}$. You're looking for
$$R:=\{(t_1,...,t_5)\in S^5\mid \sum_{i=1}^5 \mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}(t_i)\ge 1\}$$

Therefore we have
$$
R= S^5-R\setminus S^5
$$
or, written more familiarly
$$
\mathbb P(R) = 1- \mathbb P(R^C)
$$
, using the Laplace-distribution over the Sample space $S^5$.

Now we have
$$
R\setminus S^5= \{(t_1,...,t_5)\in S^5\mid \sum_{i=1}^5 \mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}(i)<1\} = \{(t_1,...,t_5)\in S^5\mid \sum_{i=1}^5 \mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}(t_i)= 0\}
 = \{(t_1,...,t_5)\in S^5\mid t_i\neq 1\} = \{(t_1,...,t_5)\in \{2,3\}^5\}= 2^5$$

And therefore we arrive at your answer $3^5-2^5$.